# Suppose that $A \in M_n$ is strictly diagonally dominant. Show that $|a_{kk}|$ $\lt C_k'$, for at least one value of $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that $A \in M_n$ is strictly diagonally dominant. Show that $|a_{kk}|$$\gt C_k'$, for at least one value of $k=1,\dots, n$, where $C_k'$ denotes $A$'s deleted absolute column sums ($a_{kk}$ is deleted).

My guess is that since $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant, $A$ must be nonsingular, and so $A^{T}$ is nonsingular as well. However, if we deny the assertion, then $0$ must be in the union of the Gersgorin discs. I think it's possible to lead to the contradiction that $0$ is actually an eigenvalue of $A^{T}$ in this case, but I'm stuck here.

Any solutions, hints, or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: As written, this is false (try the identity matrix).  Do you mean $|a_{kk}| > C_k'$ for some $k$?

Comment: Oops...My mistake, you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ii}| > \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \neq i} |a_{ij}| 
= \sum_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq n} |a_{ij}|
= \sum_{j=1}^n C_{j}'
$$